# v-for returns error when i want to write arrays

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want my array data to be shown in the list, but I'm seeing the following error:

```
error: Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives (vue/require-v-for-key) at src\components\Kubismyk.vue:5:9:
```

My component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
      <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="ninja in ninjas">{{ ninja }}</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
      return {
          title:'hello world',
          ninjas: ['yoshi','mario','ryu']
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please show the error message in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [unique key for `v-key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State) when using `v-for` loops so that Vue can track each node's identity. You could use `index` in this case:

```html
<li v-for="(ninja, index) in ninjas" :key="index">
```

You can discover more information about this linter rule in [`vue/require-v-for-key` docs](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/require-v-for-key.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind a v-key when using v-for:

````
<ul v-for="ninja in ninjas" v-bind:key="ninja.id">
<li>{{ ninja.name }}
</ul>```
````